# Requests to Ktor hosted on Android with Jetty engine are timing out

Tags: android, jetty, ktor

I am hosting a ktor server on an android device with the Jetty engine and inconsistently the requests will take 30s to time out with the `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired` exception. If that happens the response will still correctly be sent to Postman just after the 30s are up. The issue will sometimes be fixed by restarting the device but this is inconsistent as a solution and not actually solving the issue. If the issue isn't occurring the requests will take at most 500ms to respond.

Here are the logs with the 30s disparity happening after the `Selector sun.nio.ch. PollSelectorImpl@842116 waiting with 1 keys` line.

````
update org.eclipse.jetty.io. ChannelEndPoint$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0@8555f29
Key interests updated 0 -> 1 on SocketChannelEndPoint@1121ed6{1=/172.16.30.79:6
updates 0
Selector sun.nio.ch. PollSelectorImpl@842116 waiting with 1 keys
SocketChannelEndPoint@1121ed6{1=/172.16.30.79:8443,=/172.16.30.75:59459,OPEN,1
SocketChannelEndPoint@1121ed6{1=/172.16.30.79:8443,r=/172.16.30.75:59459,OPEN,1
SocketChannelEndPoint@1121ed6{=/172.16.30.79:8443,r=/172.16.30.75:59459,OPEN,1
onFail FillInterest@721d4b0{AC.ReadCB05f71d2d{HttpConnection@5f71d2d::SocketChé
java.util.concurrent. TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30002/30000 ms
a org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:171)
atorg.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.idleCheck(IdleTimeout.java:113)
atorg.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.$r8$lambda$CXAKayJ04fsmNPZKEYcCFb0CwwE
atorg.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown‹
at java.util. concurrent. ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFUtureTask.rur
close HttpParser{s=START,0 of - 1}
START - -> CLOSE
HttpConnection@5f71d2d::SocketChannelEndPoint@1121ed6{1=/172.16.30.79:8443,г=/1
java.util.concurrent. TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30002/30000 ms
a org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:171)
a org.eclipse.jetty.io. IdleTimeout.idleCheck(IdleTimeout.java:113)
atorg.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.$r8$lambda$CXAKayJ04fsmNPZKEYCCFbOCwwE```
````

Comment: Can this problem be reproduced on an emulator or a local machine? Is so, can you please share a code snippet to reproduce it?